# Deploying grails project in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, grails, jar

I'm getting the Valiate Jar file error when deploying the application in tomcat 7.0.57.Chaning the tomcat version to 8 is the only solution for this problem? 
This is my Error log:

> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO: validateJarFile(/home/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO: validateJarFile(/home/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.

After Deploying the application in Tomcat server 8 I get the below error:

SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[az84cimap02.am.freescale.net].StandardContext[/cienold]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scanWebInfClasses(TldScanner.java:401)
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /home/cimwebadm/tomcat_instances/cien-grails/webapps/cienold.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Comment: which version of grails do you use : grails 2.x or 3.x ?

Comment: Grails 3.x and tomcat 8

Answer (score 1):

Go to your build.gradle file and change

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

to

```
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

Then your war will deploy to Tomcat 7 as well.

Comment: it din't work for me. Even I changed my tomcat version to 8 that also didn't make any difference

Comment: I have several Grails 3 applications running on Tomcats (version 7 right now). The aforementioned change makes sure that libraries that are already provided by Tomcat (or other web application servers) are not copied into the WAR file, for example tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar.

Are you sure you have recreated the war file after you made the change?

Comment: yes I have reproduced the War file and Deployed.Buit still the Error Persist

Comment: Does Using custom profiles make any impact on the tomcat server?